# why 9 rows are fetch from this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

```
Given 2 tables T1 and T2.
T1  T2 
A   1 
B   2
C   3
```

> ```
> You make a query SELECT * FROM T1, T2.
> ```

```
What is the no: of rows that are fetched from this query?
```

> Answer is 9

Comment: You have these 9 rows as output?

Comment: Google: sql implicit "CROSS JOIN"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This query results in [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) because no other conditions are provided. Every row from first table is matched with every row from second table.

The result is

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 3
C 1
C 2
C 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Because each record from the first table is returned along with each record of the second table and the result is not filtered.

The exact output will be:

```
T1  T2 
A   1 
A   2
A   3 
B   1
B   2
B   3
C   1
C   2
C   3
```

(order may vary)

Answer (score 2):

It is a cartesian product: select all rows from one table (3) and all rows from another table (3) and combine them, so 3*3=9.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you asked it to do. You got all the rows from `T1` and all the rows from `T2`. They don't just get added together -- that won't work if the columns are different, for example, though you can do this with `UNION` -- they get merged in what's known as a "cartesian product". You essentially get all combinations of rows from both tables. And `3*3 = 9`.